# Clojure def giving UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: clojure

I am trying to ping fleetdb from a clojure client.  When I ping the server, I get back the response "pong", but when I try to save it to a variable using `def`, I get  "UnsupportedOperationException applyTo".

```
(use 'fleetdb.client)

(def client (connect {:host "127.0.0.1", :port 3400}))

(client ["ping"]) ; get back "pong" as response

(type  (client ["ping"]))   ;java.lang.String

(print (client ["ping"]))   ; get back "pong" as response

(def isalive (client ["ping"])) 

; UnsupportedOperationException applyTo  fleetdb.client.proxy$java.lang.Object$IFn

; $ILookup$Closeable$9aed515e.applyTo (:-1)
```

Tried with clojure 1.2 and 1.3.0-alpha4

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the client proxy does not define the *applyTo* method which is part of IFn interface:

https://github.com/mmcgrana/fleetdb-client/blob/master/src/fleetdb/client.clj#L54

This will work:

```
user> (def x (.invoke client ["ping"]))
#'user/x
```

Need to check out, why *applyTo* is used instead of *invoke*